# microtonal accidentals and theoretical key signatures

Tags: key-signatures

In microtonal music, theoretically, microtonal accidentals can be placed to key signature.
So can we think microtonal key signatures as a kind of theoretical key signatures?

I really appreciate any answer you can provide. Thanks!

Comment: Music is art, so we can do anything we want. I can see situations in microtonal music where you might run into limitations of the notation that might make using a key signature problematic. If the piece or passage only uses seven or fewer notes per octave, then a microtonal key signature might be interesting and helpful to musicians.

Answer (score 1):

We could very much do this, but it would only really make sense if notes generally have a specific microtonal accidental. E.g. if you want to have every E a quarter tone lower you might place a quartertone key accidental. If there is no general such behaviour you should probably place explicit microtonal accidentals. Else the whole thing would easily become quite confusing.

Also if you have many such general rules I think key accidentals would quickly become very confusing, as you’d need to keep in mind microtonal deviations for each given note.